# How can I make Chromium use a different ALSA device?

Tags: sound-card, chromium, alsa

I need one instance of Chromium on Linux to target a different sound card than the default, including Flash. Is there anyway to do this easily?

Answer (score 5):

First, use `aplay -l` to get the identifier of the alternative sound card you want to use. In the following example, it's `AUDIO`.

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CONEXANT Analog [CONEXANT Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: AUDIO [USB  AUDIO], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Next, create an alternative ALSA configuration file (I used `.asoundrc.usb`) and fill it with the following content (based on [a solution for a similar problem](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-configure-flash-9-in-firefox-to-use-a-specific-alsa-device-629183/)). Don't forget to replace `AUDIO` with the identifier you obtained in the previous step.

```
pcm.usb { type hw; card AUDIO; }
ctl.usb { type hw; card AUDIO; }

pcm.!default pcm.usb
ctl.!default ctl.usb
```

The only thing left is to modify the startup (desktop or menu shortcut, script, alias, etc.) of your browser to set the `ALSA_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable (documented on the [ALSA project page](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/LibEnvVars)) to the file you created.